# Project deletion date in Google API Console

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-console-developer

As specified in the [Google Platform Console Help](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en), there is a period of 7 days to remove a project once it has been selected for deletion. And it also says this period could vary depending on the billing setup.

This period has expired and I want to know what was the deletion date and what is the expected date for this operation to be completed. Is this possible from the Google API Console?. This is needed in order to create extra Firebase projects, I have reached the limit and I can't create new projects until the older ones are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could take up to 30-day period now to be completely removed. From [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en) "Note that after the 7-day waiting period ends, the time it takes to completely delete a project may vary.".